# Apache reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, apache-http-server

I am trying to setup reverse proxy on Apache/2.2.9 on Ubuntu server to reverse proxy the directory /someapp to another server, using the following config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /someapp http://somehost:8080/someapp/
ProxyPassReverse http://somehome:8080/someapp/ /someapp
```

When I browse to http://host/someapp I am redirected to http://somehome:8080/someapp instead of proxying the request.

Is there something I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your last line should be the other way around:

ProxyPassReverse http://somehome:8080/someapp/ /someapp

should be:

ProxyPassReverse /someapp http://somehome:8080/someapp/